# Detect when loading of someone else's web page into webview is done with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, webview, google-chrome-app

I use jQuery to initiate the loading of a page into a Chrome App webview. I would like to know when it has finished loading (I don't care so much about whether all resources have loaded).

All solutions I have found so far require me to have code in the page itself, but the the pages I am loading are not under my control, so I cannot just edit them to include the code I want. I want my external code, that initiates the load, to be notified. For example, something like this external code:

```
jqWebview.src = "someone_elses_page.html";                // This works.
jqWebview.ready( function(){console.log('Yippee.');} );   // This doesn't.
```

But the above gives me: Error in event handler for (unknown): TypeError: jqWebview.ready is not a function

How can I find out when the page is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

I found my own answer:

```
jqWebview.addEventListener( 'contentload',function(){console.log('yup');} );
```

Found it here: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#dom_events